# I keep getting a compilation error on Arduino IDE using MFRC522 RFID saying that it needs a data type

Tags: arduino, rfid

I have been using the standard code for Arduino to get this RFID to work

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define SS_PIN 10
#define RST_PIN 9
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance.

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);   // Initiate a serial communication
  SPI.begin();      // Initiate  SPI bus
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();   // Initiate MFRC522
  Serial.println("Approximate your card to the reader...");
  Serial.println();

}
void loop() 
{
  // Look for new cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) 
  {
    return;
  }
  // Select one of the cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) 
  {
    return;
  }
  //Show UID on serial monitor
  Serial.print("UID tag :");
  String content= "";
  byte letter;
  for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) 
  {
     Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
     Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
     content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " "));
     content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX));
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Message : ");
  content.toUpperCase();
  if (content.substring(1) == "BD 31 15 2B") //change here the UID of the card/cards that you want to give access
  {
    Serial.println("Authorized access");
    Serial.println();
    delay(3000);
  }

 else   {
    Serial.println(" Access denied");
    delay(3000);
  }
}
```

And I keep getting these errors

```
RFID:6: error: 'MFRC522' does not name a type
RFID.ino: In function 'void setup()':
RFID:12: error: 'mfrc522' was not declared in this scope
RFID.ino: In function 'void loop()':
RFID:20: error: 'mfrc522' was not declared in this scope
RFID:25: error: 'mfrc522' was not declared in this scope
RFID:33: error: 'mfrc522' was not declared in this scope
```

Any reasons why this is happening? I'm using Arduino 1.0.5 because my Uno drivers won't load with a newer version. If there's a post about this already I couldn't find it, so a link to that would also be appreciated